# Spotify play button for users playlists "sorry, this playlist is empty"

Tags: spotify

I want to create a play button for Spotify for a users playlist. For some reason it returns an error message: "sorry, this playlist is empty"

This is the code i'm using:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:robleach:playlist:5Cv2iMSoeJvFKgQeweFhFD" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And it returns the error: "sorry, this playlist is empty"

If however I use the example code on Spotify's site, which is essentially the same code it works? I'm presuming it may be down to it being a different user?

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:erebore:playlist:788MOXyTfcUb1tdw4oC7KJ" width="250" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Has anyone had this trouble before? Anyone got a work around?

Cheers
Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code and yes, it's because it is a different user. This is a server issue.

1. The play button service is having problem and can't return some playlists (that are not in its cache), because the underlying playlist system is having problems.
2. The error message is lying.

It has happened before and there is no good workaround. :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jooon good to know i'm not doing anything wrong! I did have a suspicion that their system was having problems. Do you know how long the problem lasted last time?

Comment: Almost a day. About the same this time. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, so that's what's going on! You know, if you post an individual song, it works perfectly. I'm posting all the songs in my playlist separately (a pain) until the problem is fixed.

Comment: You can also use the trackset syntax to publish a list of tracks without having them in a playlist: https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:PREFEREDTITLE:5Z7ygHQo02SUrFmcgpwsKW,1x6ACsKV4UdWS2FMuPFUiT,4bi73jCM02fMpkI11Lqmfe (docs here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/documentation/ )