# The Spotify Play Button is saying "Sorry, this playlist is empty."

Tags: spotify

I have noticed some people have had this problem before. I have a site with playlists and added the Play Button yesterday. today i noticed that on some of the playlists (eventhough they exist) the play button returns Sorry, this playlist is empty.

The code im using looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:veri:playlist:2gmzIePbPeZFxCuFRCmy0A& theme=white" width="640" height="680" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Some of the playlists works fine but many are not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spotify play button for users playlists "sorry, this playlist is empty"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436799/spotify-play-button-for-users-playlists-sorry-this-playlist-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to issues with the service that resolves the playlists. We're working on improving the stability.